# mocha, mongoose - done() called multiple times

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I have test suite for testing user registration:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const { app } = require('../../');
const {User} = require('../../models/');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Register new user', () => {

    it('it should register new user and return data', done => {
        done();
        chai.request(app)
        .post('/api/users')
        .send({name: 'Alex', email:'alex@gmail.com', password: 'alextest'})
        .then(res => {
            console.log('1-st done called');
            done();

        });
    });

    it('it should display not provided data error', done => {
        chai.request(app)
        .post('/api/users')
        .send({})
        .then(res => {
            chai.expect(res).to.have.status(400);
            chai.expect(res.body.errors).to.be.an('object');
            chai.expect(res.body.errors).to.have.ownProperty('password');
            chai.expect(res.body.errors).to.have.ownProperty('email');
            chai.expect(res.body.errors).to.have.ownProperty('name');
            done();
        });
    });

    after(done => {
        User.deleteMany({}, err => {
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

And every time i run this test. There is an error. If i remove it('it should display not provided data error') test as result test suite is passed. But with this two tast cases in one test case one always be failing.

```
Server running on port 3000
api_1    |   Register new user
api_1    |     ✓ it should register new user and return data
api_1    | 2-cnd done called
api_1    |     ✓ it should display not provided data error
api_1    | 1-st done called
api_1    |     1) it should register new user and return data
api_1    | done delete many called
api_1    | 
api_1    | 
api_1    |   2 passing (121ms)
api_1    |   1 failing
api_1    | 
api_1    |   1) Register new user
api_1    |        it should register new user and return data:
api_1    |      Error: done() called multiple times
api_1    |       at /usr/src/app/test/it/auth.js:18:13
api_1    |       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
```

Cant figure out what i`m doing wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `done` twice in this test:

```
it('it should register new user and return data', done => {
  done(); // <—- ONCE
  chai.request(app)
    .post('/api/users')
    .send({name: 'Alex', email:'alex@gmail.com', password: 'alextest'})
    .then(res => {
      console.log('1-st done called');
      done(); // <—- TWICE
    });
});
```

Remove the first one.

Hope this helps.